# What should I do when templates are not flexible enough, and overloading results in code duplication

Tags: c++

Just like in title. I found myself in situation when templates are not flexible enough, and function overloading leads to code duplication.

---

Let me show some code:

```
// header.h:

inline void some_func(const unsigned int size, int * arr_1, int * arr_2) {

    // block of code #1. 
    // -- This block is identical in every overloaded instance of this function

    // Single line of code:
    // -- This line is DIFFERENT in every overloaded instance of this function
    int4 val = reinterpret_cast<int4*>(arr_1)[i];

    // block of code #2. 
    // -- This block is identical in every overloaded instance of this function
}

inline void some_func(const unsigned int size, float * arr_1, float * arr_2) {

    // block of code #1. 
    // -- This block is identical in every overloaded instance of this function

    // Single line of code:
    // -- This line is DIFFERENT in every overloaded instance of this function
    float4 val = reinterpret_cast<float4*>(arr_1)[i];

    // block of code #2. 
    // -- This block is identical in every overloaded instance of this function
}

template <typename T> inline
void some_func_warper(T * arr_1, T * arr_2) {

    // Calculate few parameters...

    // Call some_func(***)

}
```

---

As you can see, because I am vectorizing my input arrays `arr_1` & `arr_2`, I cannot write template for `some_func(***)`. I can only overload it, and that forces me to duplicate two massive blocks of code... 
 
In case of `some_func_warper(***)` using template is misleading for obvious reasons. Therefore I would like to avoid using this warper too.

**Question #1:** 
 
Is there any way to do something like this: 
"Write function template and specialize ONLY one line from that template" ??

**Question #2:** 
 
I am quite sure that answer to **Question #1:** will be **no**. 
Therefore is there any other workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two templates. One to hold the generic some_func code, and one you specialize for the type used in that line. If you are doing this vectorization in multiple places, you may find that you can use one trait class to define the type and then use it in multiple template functions.

```
template<class T>
class some_func_val_type;

template<>
class some_func_val_type<int> {
    using type = int4;
};

template<>
class some_func_val_type<float> {
    using type = float4;
};

template<class T>
inline void some_func(const unsigned int size, T * arr_1, T * arr_2) {

    // block of code #1. 
    // -- This block is identical in every overloaded instance of this function

    // Single line of code:
    typename some_func_val_type<T>::type val =
        reinterpret_cast<typename some_func_val_type<T>::type*>(arr_1)[i];

    // block of code #2. 
    // -- This block is identical in every overloaded instance of this function
}
```

Comment: sorry but i keep getting an error: `error : expected a ";"` and `error : identifier "val" is undefined` maybe you have any idea why? 
Everything is related to that `Single Line of Code`

Comment: You need to use `typename` before the `sum_func_val_type<T>::type`, due to the dependent type.  You can make it easier to read by using a typedef before.